# Randomly deleted my website folder in the public_html folder

Tags: wordpress

I have a big problem. I have 2 WordPress website in the public_html folder in the server. Called X website and Y website. The Y Website's folder contents randomly deleted. e.g: 1 week or few days. If this process is done, then the X website is not working. I open my X site in the browser, and I become the HTTP error 500. The Y's website folder is empty! After that, I upload the X and Y sites backup, and my 2 site is working. What could be a problem? Thanks for the help!

Here is the plugin list:

X Site:

```
 - 2J SlideShow (Version: 1.3.23) by: 2J Slideshow Team
 -  All In One WP Security (Version: 4.3.1) by: Tips and Tricks HQ, Peter Petreski, Ruhul, Ivy
 - Facebook Button by BestWebSoft (Version: 2.55)
 - Instagram Feed (Version: 1.5) by: Smash Balloon
 - Simple Lightbox (Version: 2.6.0) by: Archetyped
 - Team Builder (Version: 1.2.3) by: wpshopmart
 - Widget Context (Version: 1.0.5) by: Kaspars Dambis
 - Wordfence Security (Version: 6.3.21) by: Wordfence
 - WP Cerber Security & Antispam (Version 5.8) by: Gregory
 - WP Statistics (Version: 12.2.1) by: Verona Labs
 - WP-PageNavi (Version: 2.92) by: Lester 'GaMerZ' Chan
```

Y Site:

```
- Akismet Anti-Spam (Version: 4.0.1) by: Automattic
 - All In One WP Security (Version: 4.3.1) by: Tips and Tricks HQ, Peter
   Petreski, Ruhul, Ivy
 - Captcha (Version: 4.3.6) by: simplywordpress
 - Divi Builder (Version: 2.0.51) by: Elegant Themes
 - Easy Video Player (Version: 1.1.7) by: naa986
 - Facebook Widget (Version: 4.2.1) by: Milap Patel
 - Image Watermark (Version: 1.6.1) by: dFactory)
 - Monarch Plugin (Version: 1.3.23) by: Elegant Themes
 - TinyMCE Advanced (Version: 4.6.7) by: Andrew Ozz
 - Wordfence Security (Version: 6.3.21) by: Wordfence
 - WP Content Copy Protection & No Right Click (Version: 1.6) by: wp-buy
 - YouTube (Version: 11.8.3) by: EmbedPlus Team
```

Comment: check your server logs and contact host support

Comment: And change all passwords, including FTP/SFTP.